# SSRS create maps from data

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, routes, mapping

I have learned to create maps from the dataset in SSRS but I do not see how to modify the map based on the parameter values.

For instance, I load the sql which contains 100 routes. The parameter would limit the user to view the information on one route. But the map does not seem to be affected by the parameter; it shows the entire dataset no mater the parameter.

How to force the map to also be limited by the parameter?

Comment: How are you applying the filter to the dataset? Post your code that returns the data from the table as there is not enough info here at the moment.

Comment: Use the same dataset you're using to populate the map and create a table displaying those values. If your table displays all value that shows you your parameter is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you either a) Added a filter to the dataset, or b) added a WHERE clause in your data set with the route set to the report parameter?

Example:

```
SELECT route
FROM   route_table
WHERE  route = @routeparameter
```